# String is not a function JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to set a value to a field, this is the html:

```
<form name="myForm"> 
<input type="text" id="user">
</form>
```

And the javascript:

```
window.onload = init;
function init() {
generateUser();
//more code... 
}

function generateUser(){
var generated = "usr_"+Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
document.myForm.user.value(generated);
}
```

I cant find a way to set that value, always getting "String not a function".

Comment: `value` isn't a function.  It's a string.  It's the *value* of the input field.

Comment: Don't confuse it with `.val()` from JQuery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be:

```
document.myForm.user.value = generated;
```

It is not a method it is a property...

Answer (score 1):

Exists very useful function to find element in any place on the page by element id - getElementById, you can use it

```
document.getElementById("user").value = generated;
```